# PWM controller and analog circuits

Tags: motor, pwm, potentiometer, circuits

I’m trying to fix an item controlled by analog circuitry. No luck on that. I can get a motor to run but can not figure out the speed control circuit. It uses NPN and PNP transistors with variable trimpot resistors.

But if I use a PWM low-voltage motor controller, it works on a test with the motor. Can the PWM be integrated into analog circuits or can I just bypass the analog part and replace it with PWM? Would the stand-alone PWM hold the motor at a steady speed on the pot? The circuit does have some other functions beyond the motor controller.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: PWM creates quite alot of electrical noise.  You didn't say what this is for, but if it's for any kind of analog audio (i.e. tape deck, record player, etc..) it's gonna be bad when you turn the amp on.

Comment: *Would the stand-alone PWM hold the motor at a steady speed on the pot?* <-- unlikely unless some form of speed feedback control system is used.

Comment: It’s not for audio recorder. It’s for a camera.  At most the camera would run for short bursts, 1 -3 minutes max. What’s a speed control system example? Would it be another chip? I’m not that familiar with electronics.